# How to get all links on page to play sound on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a lot of links and instead of inserting

```
onclick="clicksound.playclip()"
```

into each one, is there a way i can all of the links on the page to use that code with it on the page in only one area?

Answer (score 1):

If by "links" you mean all `anchors`,

It can be done using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    clicksound.playclip()
  });
});
```

Or pure javaScript:

```
document.links.addEventListener("click", clicksound.playclip);
```

Comment: Not all A elements are links. [*document.links*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#dom-document-links) is a live [HTMLCollection](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection) which doesn't have an *onclick* method.

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to the body, see if a click came from a link, play a sound if it did. You could also use *document.links* to get all the links and add a listener to each one, but that seems inefficient.

Note that not all A elements are links.

#### Edit

Here's a plain JS solution, the *upTo* and listener attachment parts should be in your library:

```
function upTo(root, tagName) {  
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  do {
    root = root.parentNode;
    if (root.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return root;
    }
  } while (root.parentNode && root.parentNode.tagName)
}

function playSound(evt) {
  var evt = evt || window.event;
  var tgt = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (tgt && tgt.nodeType != 1) tgt = tgt.parentNode;
  tgt = tgt.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a'? tgt : upTo(tgt, 'a');
  if (tgt && tgt.href && tgt.href != '') annoyUserWithSound();
}

window.onload = function() {
  if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', playSound, false);
  } else if (document.body.attachEvent) {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick', playSound);
  }
}

function annoyUserWithSound(){
  console.log('be annoyed by sound…');
}
```